# VBA: Reference a sheet in another workbook that may or may not be closed

Tags: vba, excel

Please can someone help me? I'm trying to reference a sheet in another workbook but the function returns a #VALUE! error. I think it's this bit that is causing the error:

```
'Set variable for other Workbook
Dim oh As Workbook
'This filepath may need to be changed if the file is moved
Set oh = Workbooks.Open("C:\Filepath\Filename.xlsx")

'Set variable for cs sheet in the other workbook
Dim cs As Worksheet
Set cs = oh.Worksheets("cs")
```

The entire code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Function WLR(CN, Ct)

'Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

''Change this to refer to sheet in other workbook later.
''For now, it refers to the cs sheet on this workbook
'Dim cs As Worksheet
'Set cs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cs")

'Set variable for other Workbook
Dim oh As Workbook
'This filepath may need to be changed if the file is moved
Set oh = Workbooks.Open("C:\Filepath\Filename.xlsx")

'Set variable for cs sheet in the other workbook
Dim cs As Worksheet
Set cs = oh.Worksheets("cs")

'Get Info from cs sheet
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

With cs
    Do While i <= .Rows.Count 'Check you haven't exceeded the limit
        If .Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then 'Check the cell isn't blank
            If .Cells(i, 2) = CN Then 'Check if course name is in list
                Exit Do 'Exit loop with i set to correct row if CN is found
            End If
        Else
            WLR = "" 'Return blank if course name not found
            'Turn on screen updating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

'Turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Set Result
WLR = .Cells(i, 6)

End With

End Function
```

I tried copying the sheet to this workbook, commenting out the bit about referring to the other worksheet and uncommenting the bit about the cs sheet within this workbook and this worked but I really need it to refer to the other workbook. Any ideas? I've searched on here and tried many things such as using the sheet index but I'm really stuck now.

EDIT: The function doesn't crash, it returns the VALUE#! error. I think the issue is where I try to reference the sheet. I tried before, just referencing the workbook and that didn't return an error.

Comment: What's your goal? Return a reference to a Range or to the value of a Range? BTW, you're passing your function the "Ct" parameter which isn't used in it

Comment: My goal is to return the value of a range.

I will be building on this and the Ct parameter will be used in future. I would just like to get this bit working first before I go any further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have your function defined as

```
Function WLR(CN, Ct) as string
```

Comment: I tried your code and tried referencing another workbook. Your code seems to work fine. The only way I could get a #VALUE! error value is when the cell(i,6) is containing the #VALUE! error itself.

I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 too. It can't be the contents of the cell either as I tried copying the sheet to the same workbook and that worked.

Did you amend anything else to get it working? Could it be because I'm using Office 365?

Comment: No @JeniD I didn't append anything to the code except for the file name & location. I'm not sure if it's an Office 365 issue though :(

Comment: Thanks, I will try this at home then. At least I know my first piece of VBA code that's not from an exercise book works for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it - turns out that you can't open another workbook within a function so I opened the other workbook in the background when the original workbook opened and then closed it without prompting to save on exit.